# Missing return statement does not produce an error

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, return

This is just a curiosity thing, but I have the following code. I'm adding elements to a linked list recursively. This code works perfectly fine.

But when I remove the return statement from the insert function, it does not throw an error. The program compiles and when I run it I get a "Segmentation Fault".

I find this strange. Shouldn't a missing return statement produce an error?

Just wondering why it wouldn't:

```
Node* insert(Node* node, int values[]) {
    for (int i=0; i < 9; i++) {
        insertRecursively(node, values[i]);
    }
    return node;
}

int main() {
    int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};  
    node = insert(node, a);
    print(node);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 'Print', not 'throw'. Compilation errors are printed. They're not exceptions.

Comment: What command are you using to build this, or is it in an IDE? If it's a makefile project, errors might be suppressed, ie `ERROR = -Wno-all`

Comment: Not returning a value is UB, no diagnostic required.